# Image on Mobile won't display

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, mobile-browser

I've built a website for a friend and it works great on computer browsers, but on mobile it doesn't display for ONE image (The other images work fine).. This is at least on the iPhone browser and Samsung Galaxy 4 browser. On a Nokia phone the image displays fine.

I actually built this website on top of another designers work, but as far as I can tell there is no specific javascript embedded anywhere for mobile browsers.

The following HTML and CSS correspond to the image that doesn't show:

```
<div id="main-content-left-container">
        <ul id="left-bullets">
            #Some bullets
    </ul>
    <img id="ups-map" src="./images/ups-map.jpg">  #Problem here
</div>


#ups-map {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
}

#ups-map:hover {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be caused by?

Comment: define "acts funny" that could be anything from it not displaying, to it turning your beard green.

Comment: wow. I can't believe I said that. I meant it doesn't display. Fixed above

Comment: Should it be:"<img id="ups-map" src="../images/ups-map.jpg" />" instead? (Notice the addition "." before the path and the trailing "/" at the end of the img link.  Fiddle?

Comment: the "./" says current folder "../" says go up 1 folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rvf9R/

```
    <div id="main-content-left-container">
        <ul id="left-bullets">
            <li>bullet</li>
            <li>bullet</li>
            <li>bullet</li>
            <li>bullet</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="ups-map">
            <img src="http://pittsburghjedi.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/LOG-ren-and-stimpy-1552749-1280-1024.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <style>
    img { max-width: 100%; }

    #ups-map {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 280px;
    }

    #ups-map:hover {
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: I actually have the max-width set already (Sorry I didn't include)

Comment: Yes, in you're demo your controlling the width/height on the image. you actually shouldn't do that with mobile/tablets. Is this website up on the internet? I could better pin point the problem

Comment: website is www.justiceop.com

Comment: I just checked your website on my samsung galaxy 3 and it works fine